# Scroll to HTML content in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to programmatically **scroll** to a **HTML element** that is displayed in a **WebView**?

The WebView API only provides a `scrollTo(x,y)` method, but I can't find a way to determine the position of a displayed element.

**Solution**

Using Javascript:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not directly with WebView but with javascript. If you have a js function to scroll to an element such as this :

```
function scrollTo(element){
   document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();
}
```

You can call it from WebView with

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:scrollTo('element')");
```

Just make sure javascript is enabled in WebView

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```